# BatchTest (Ant) not "executing" JUnit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, junit4

The following ANT script executes the 2 tests mentioned:

```
<target name="tests">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="x.atest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <test name="x.ytest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>              
        <classpath refid="ab.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

However, when I am trying to change it to BatchTest, it builds successfully but does not execute the tests:

```
<target name="tests">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest todir="${junit.output.dir}" fork="yes">
            <fileset dir="${tests.dir}">
                <include name="**/.class" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <classpath refid="ab.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

I am out of my wits now as what might be missing here. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what in ${tests.dir} I can't really tell, but does ${tests.dir} contain the compiled unit tests or the source code for the tests? if it's the latter try changing   `<include name="**/.class" />` to `<include name="**/.java" />` or pointing the dir atrribute of fileset to whereever the compiled tests are outputted to